# How to find unique keys, tabel storage size in CosmosDB container?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am learning `CosmosDB` (coming from `AWS Dynamo`) and struggling to find some base info about the container from UI, such as following. I am looking into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview this but so far I have not found needed info.

- How to see total size of the container? In Dynamo, you would see that under `overview` section, but I do not see such for CosmosDB.
- How to see unique keys? I can see `partition key` under `settings` but like Dynamo, is there a way to see all indexes such as `Global indexes`? I checked `Indexing Policy` for CosmosDB, but don't see any info regarding keys. Does that mean this container doesn't have any unique keys?

I tried to find such info online, but couldn't. For Cosmos, I want to find out which unique keys I have to create based on my requirements. But, lets the container is already created by someone else, and I want to see info about unique keys, etc. How can I do that? Same with container size.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure Portal doesn't show everything for a container unfortunately.

The best way to get all the information for a container is to use PowerShell or Azure CLI. Example below

```
az cosmosdb sql container show -g myResourceGroup -a mycosmosaccount -d myDatabase -n myContainer
```

This will show everything. Partition key, index policy, unique keys and will also show storage size by physical partition. Just add up for entire container.

Comment: I'll try this. On the same note, is it possible to have a unique key with multiple values. i.e., partition key can be `/id` and unique key `/name#city#zip#state`, etc. Is this even possible?

Comment: You can create synthetic partition keys that essentially are concatenated values of properties. Learn more about that here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/synthetic-partition-keys. You can also define a hierarchy of partition keys now as well. This feature is just recently released in Preview. More details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys